# apply macros to a vector

Tags: clojurescript, clojure.spec

Imagine having a dynamically generated specs for `cat`

```
[:first-name string? :surname string?]
```

Now I want to use them with `cljs.spec.alpha/cat`.

In plain Clojure I can write a macro that will cons a macro with args and eval it, right? But for ClojureScript it is not as easy because `macros` are compile-time beasts and also `eval` is also kinda different thing.

What are workarounds to apply my vector of args to a macro in ClojureScript?

Comment: I think I can't do it, so I'll go using `cat-impl` directly.

Comment: Is the vector defined at compile-time or will it be dynamically constructed at runtime?

Comment: @olieidel it will be defined at compile time (see https://github.com/fl00r/trout)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this isn't easy for dynamic/data-driven specs, but that's apparently being worked on for a future release.

I think the only workarounds are to `eval`, or use cljs.spec.alpha internal implementation as you mentioned.

```
cljs.user=> (def cat-args [:x string?])
#'cljs.user/cat-args
cljs.user=> (s/def ::foo (eval (cons 's/cat cat-args)))
:cljs.user/foo
cljs.user=> (s/conform ::foo '("foo"))
{:x "foo"}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am talking about cljs env, not clojure one. you don't have `args` on compile time, and macros are not runtime in cljs

Comment: are you using `cljs.core/eval`? because it shouldn't work as you wrote unless you redefined `*eval*` (https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/STARevalSTAR)

Comment: @fl00r yes, I just tried `(cljs.core/eval (cons 's/cat cat-args))` and it works. FWIW I'm doing this in a [Planck REPL](https://github.com/planck-repl/planck).

Comment: seems like a decent tool

Answer (score 2):

Is your spec generated symbolically at compile time? If so, perhaps you could use a macro as you had suggested.

```
(ns foo.core)

(defmacro gen-spec []
  `'~(into '[:first-name string?] '[:surname string?]))

(defmacro apply-macro [name args-form]
  `(~name ~@(eval args-form)))
```

Here is an example using it

```
$ clj -m cljs.main
ClojureScript 1.10.339
cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])
nil
cljs.user=> (require-macros 'foo.core)
nil
cljs.user=> (foo.core/gen-spec)
[:first-name string? :surname string?]
cljs.user=> (foo.core/apply-macro s/cat (foo.core/gen-spec))
{:cljs.spec.alpha/op :cljs.spec.alpha/pcat, :ps [#object[cljs$core$string_QMARK_] #object[cljs$core$string_QMARK_]], :ret {}, :ks [:first-name :surname], :forms [cljs.core/string? cljs.core/string?], :rep+ nil}
```

Note how `gen-spec` builds up the spec symbolically and returns it in quoted form.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your feedback. Unfortunately the specs themselves are being generated from another data structure in compile time. So I don't have them in a ready to use form. Look an example in Readme (https://github.com/fl00r/trout). So I can't use your approach.